# Eclipse: Need to update some register prior to downloading bin file

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Oxygen (4.7.3a) for an embedded C work project. There are multiple processors and I'd like to configure some registers prior to downloading the binary image. Eclipse/Debug Configuration/Startup has a Run/Restart Command area which allows commands (like register writes) to be run. I cannot find what this script register write format is.
I have tried:

monitor memU32 0x22002222=0x0005A5AF

It then error with: invalid command name "memU32". Is there a description of what the expected format is? I found this script in a different project, but it doesn't seem to work.
My goal is to be able to set a register to a value, prior to downloading the binary image to RAM.

Answer (score 0):

The 'set' command can be used to set register values. The Debugger Command window appears to link to the GDB, therefore the GDB commands are used here.

set *((int *) 0x22002222)=0x0005A5AF